# Jest/Vue test utils - How to test functions are called when key is pressed?

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

I have an event that added using `onMounted()` method using `window.addEventListener`. How to test that my method goPrevChannel() or goNextChannel() are called when I press `arrow down` or `arrow up` key?

**Component.vue**

```
setup: () => {
   function goPrevChannel() {
      // Implementation
   }

   function goNextChannel() {
      // Implementation
   }

   onMounted(() => {
      const listener = (evt: any) => {
        switch (evt.key) {
          case "ArrowDown":
            goNextChannel();
            break;
          case "ArrowUp":
            goPrevChannel();
            break;
        }
      };

      const event = "keydown";
      window.addEventListener(event, listener);
    });
}
```

This is what I have tried but it doesn't work
Component.test.ts

```
describe("Test", () => {
  test("trigger keydown event", async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Component);

    const spy = (wrapper.vm.goNextChannel = jest.fn());
    const event = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", { key: "down" });
    document.dispatchEvent(event);
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();

    expect(spy).toBeCalled();
  });
})
```

Comment: You can't, this is how JS works, you can't change local scope from the outside. Proceed from the fact that anything that's declared inside a component with composition api needs to be tested as a single unit, this restricts a way in which code needs to be structured